# How to limit the pagination to fetch only 2 items via pagination at a time only and not all objects?

Tags: django

I have a pagination working on my posts.

Here is my model:-

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = PostForNewsFeed
    template_name = 'feed/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 2 # add this
    count_hit = True
    slug_field = 'slug'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
        'popular_posts': PostForNewsFeed.objects.order_by('-hit_count_generic__hits')[:3],
        })
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in PostForNewsFeed.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked           
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            Q(user_name=self.request.user) |
            Q(user_name__profile__friends__user=self.request.user)
        ).distinct()
```

Here is my template:-

```
{% if is_paginated %}

    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="/home?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="/home?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

I would like to have it fetch only 2 items at a time and fetch next 2 items instead of all the items in the table.

Comment: Please include the part of your template that renders items. This is just pagination controls.

Comment: That is just a bunch of html tags...What I need is code in Class Based Views to enable pagination for only 2 records

Comment: You've already updated your ListView [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview). It won't work if you haven't updated your template to get items from `page_obj` instead of `object_list`. That's why I want to see your template code.